# Why component name must be enclosed in tag when we render it

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am just curious why we have to enclose a component name in tags when we render it.
We can do without it also.

For example

```
function TemporaryName() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Stack Overflow Question</h1>
            <h1>Stack Overflow Question</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<TemporaryName />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

This is enclosed and the line

```
ReactDOM.render(TemporaryName(), document.getElementById("root"))
```

also gives the same result.
I know there has to be some meaning to it and I want to know why? Please help

Comment: In this case it works, but it wouldn't if you use any hooks in the `TemporaryName` function. This is because the second example doesn't get compiled to a `React.createElement`-call.

Comment: Thank you I understood this now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example is calling TemporaryName as a function, and then passing the output to render. Basically, it's as though you wrote:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <div>
    <h1>Stack Overflow Question</h1>
    <h1>Stack Overflow Question</h1>
  </div>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

It's fine to pass a `<div>` into `ReactDOM.render`, so you didn't see a problem, but you will run into issues with more complicated components. As soon as you try to use any hooks in `TemporaryName`, you will get an error. You'll be trying to call the hooks *before* calling `ReactDOM.render`, which does not work.

Option 1 will work with hooks. With that, you use the JSX tags to create a react element, and pass that element into `ReactDOM.render`. This doesn't call your function at this time, so there's no misuse of hooks. A little later, react will call your component and the hooks will work since we'll be in the middle of react's render cycle.

Example of something that will fail with the second approach:

```
function TemporaryName() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Stack Overflow');
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name} Question</h1>
      <h1>{name} Question</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because when you're declaring your component you're declaring a function: `function TemporaryName()`

Comment: I get that but if we could do it that way why are we enclosing it in a tag then?